# Do analytic functions on open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ with an analytic square root form a sheaf?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, differential-topology

I'm trying to learn algebraic geometry and am trying to think about what kinds of things are presheafs but not sheafs.

One exercise I had was to show that bounded holomorphic functions on open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ do not form a sheaf.  This is pretty obvious: $D_1(0), D_2(0), ...$ form an open cover of $\mathbb{C}$, and $f_n: D_n(0) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by $f_n(z) = z$ is holomorphic on $D_n(0)$ and bounded, and the restriction of any $f_n, f_m$ to $D_n(0) \cap D_m(0)$ gives you the same thing.  If we had a sheaf structure, then there would be a bounded holomorphic function $g$ on $\mathbb{C}$ (necessarily $g(z) = z$) which restricts to $f_n$ on $D_n(0)$ for each $n$, which is absurd.

What about the presheaf of holomorphic functions on open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ which have holomorphic square roots?  This shouldn't be a sheaf, but I'm having trouble seeing why, mostly because I'm not really comfortable with saying with certainty that a given function has no holomorphic square root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every non-zero holomorphic function has a holomorphic square root on any simply connected open set. Pick any open $\Omega$ with a function $f:\Omega\to\mathbb C$ which does not has a square root and consider the covering of $\Omega$ by the discs it contains.

Comment: How do you know that you can get the restrictions to common open discs to work out, considering you have two possible square roots?  For example, I was thinking of $f(z) = z$ on an annulus containing the unit circle.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: If $D$ is a disc contained in $\Omega$, then $f|_D$ has a holomorphic square root, so that $f|_D$ is in $\mathcal F(D)$. This gives us a family $\{f|_D\}_{\text{$D$ a disc contained in $\Omega$}}$ of sections of the sheaf over a covering of $\Omega$. It is obvious that they glue correctly. Yet there is no section of the sheaf on the whole of $\Omega$ which restricts to them.

Comment: I guess I'm saying I don't understand how they glue correctly.  I'd need to know more about the square root function to tell, and there's more than one way to define a holomorphic square root in a disc, each way noncanonical.

Comment: You are not understanding the definition of the presheaf $\mathcal F$. If $U$ is an open set, then $\mathcal F(U)$ is the set of all homolorphic functions $h:U\to\mathbb C$ such that there exists an holomorphic $g:U\to\mathbb C$ with $h=g^2$. You are trying to glue square roots, and there is no reason to do that...

Comment: I just understood, thank you for answering.